# vb.net save List(of t) for a later use

Tags: vb.net

I want store List(of t) in `My.Settings.list` but there are no type in the type list. I Googled it, tryed this:

```
Public Class ListOfMyClass
    Inherits List(Of MyClass)
End Class
```

but it didn't work, just simply didn't save to settings.

Please suggest any variant of saving for a later use

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29130/Windows-Forms-Creating-and-Persisting-Custom-User

Comment: There is no "System.Collections.Generic.SortedList" in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: It exists:`Dim list = New System.Collections.Generic.SortedList(Of String, String)`. However, the link shows how to create a custom application setting in general, this collection is just an example. Let your class inherit from `ApplicationSettingsBase` and add a public property which returns your `List(Of MyClass)`. `MyClass` has to be `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize to JSON and store it somewhere as a regular string.

Answer (score 0):

Xml Serialization is an option. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx)